# Шифрование с помощью компонентов Delphi/C++ Builder

Tags: алгоритм, криптография, шифрование

Приветствую, программеры! В средах Delphi и C++ Builder имеются стандартные компоненты для шифрования (дешифрования) на закладке IndyMisc: IdEncoderXXE, IdEncoderUUE..., и соответствующие им IdDecoder* для дешифрования. Мне вдруг стало интересно, по каким алгоритмам каждый из этих компонентов производит шифрование. Может, кто-нибудь знает, или это тайна разработчиков этих сред?

Comment: UUE / XXE - это же не шифрование.

Comment: А что тогда? Кодирование что-ли?

Comment: "ЮЮками кидались" в свое время в fido... старый метод, да.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, @northerner, теперь ясно. Просто я видел пример использования этих компонентов для перевода текста в непонятные человеку символы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@DelphiM0ZG](/users/3565/delphim0zg), это способ представления бинарных данных в текстовом виде.

Возьмем почтовый протокол. Хотим приложить файл к письму. Если файл бинарный, то каждый байт может представлять собой двоичный код любого числа от 0 до 255. А протокол интерпретирует некоторые коды как управляющие последовательности, то есть явно передать файл не получится.

При кодировании текстом можно использовать, например, 64 разных кода (строчные и прописные буквы, цифры, пару знаков пунктуации). То есть каждые 6 бит двоичных данных кодируем символом. И можем передавать. Правда, объем вырастает в 4/3 раза.

Answer (score 0):

Частично нашёл ответ на свой вопрос: [здесь](http://algolist.manual.ru/compress/standard/uue.php), [здесь](http://www.ishodniki.ru/art/art_progr/cpp/25.html) и [здесь](http://www.delphisite.ru/faq/uue-kodirovanie).